# Render Dynamic Components along side html in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

My application will be receiving html from an external api containing embeds which I would like to translate into components while rendering the surrounding html.  Angular version 4.2.6.

```
@Component({
selector: 'content-body',
styleUrls: [ './content-body.component.scss' ],
template: `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`
})
export class ContentBodyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @Input()
    content: string = '<p>Example string</p><p>Should render with [some-embed-to-translate data="passable-data" ]';

    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
            private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){}

    ngOnInit() {
        // Methods for converting embeds into ng-content containers/reference points that
        // can be referenced and transformed into components after init
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loadEmbeds();
    }

    loadEmbeds() {
       // Use viewContainerRef to find the location of the embed
    }
}
```

My initial thought is to translate [embeds] into ng-content tags with ids then reference the index position when creating the dynamic component in the afterviewinit.
I know that innerHTML does not bind/process components so I am looking for a way to either create a viewChild on the fly, a way to reference the index of the embed to pass to viewContainerRef.createComponent, or some other alternative where I can render dynamic html content and process embeds into components.

**Solution**

- In ngOnInit:

  - Find all embeds and replace with ng-content placeholder
    containing a unique id.
  - Register id for placeholder which will later
    also contain the component reference being created. In
- ngAfterViewInit:

  - Loop through registry use render2 to find the
    element by id.
  - Create the component factory dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory, then make a call to
    create on the factory with the element as the reference on where to
    inject (i.e. factory.create(this.injector, [], el).
  - Update the registry to contain the component reference for cleanup later on.